# Must be in the same VG

Tags: filesystems, aix

I am trying to extend the fs like this,

```
chfs -a size=+290G /Eq7_bakcup
```

but getting this error, what am I doing wrong?

```
mount: Log dev and fs dev must be in the same volume group
```

Comment: Can you check your `/etc/filesystems` to make sure it is correct for that FS?

Comment: Hi there are not same, so what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have AIX available.

you must edit `/etc/filesystems` to set `/Eq7_bakcup` log file on same volume group.

If volume `/Eq7_bakcup` is empty, I suggest you delete it and recreate it using `smit`.